# what abreviation rule or rules does the term "UX" follow?

Tags: terminology, abbreviations, acronyms, initialisms

I am intrigued by the use of the letter "x" in the abbreviation of the term "User Experience" does this follow any specific language or phonetic rules?

Comment: There are no "rules" for such abbreviations -- the person who invents the term is the "rule".  But it's not unusual to use "X" in an abbreviation for a word which starts with an "ex" sound.

Comment: Hi @HotLicks I was thinking more in terms of is it initialism or an acronym and why?

Comment: @HotLicks but do agree with you on phonetics!

Comment: Wars have been fought over whether it's "abbreviation" or "initialism" or "acronym", so I won't go into that.  As to "why?" -- well, because.  Someone simply decides that "UX" is an appropriate abbreviation, uses it, and others pick it up.

Comment: If you Google for "center for user experience research" you will find a lot of organizations that abbreviate using "X", but also [Collaborative User Experience (CUE) Research Group](http://www.watson.ibm.com/cambridge/index.shtml).

Comment: See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60440/is-ux-as-an-abbreviation-for-user-experience-meant-to-be-ironic for more info/examples about the 'x' abbreviation.

Comment: Acronyms use a subset (perhaps proper) of 'salient' letters, initial and/or near-initial, not just initial, of the expansion. But they're always prononceable as a 'word' in the default definition. Though Wikipedia terms UXB an acronym, it's not; I can't find whether other juries judge it to be an initialism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hot Licks points out in a comment, several posters provide background on the use of *UX* as a short form of "user experience" in response to the question [Is 'UX' as an abbreviation for 'user experience' meant to be ironic?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60440/is-ux-as-an-abbreviation-for-user-experience-meant-to-be-ironic) posted on the Stack Exchange's own User Experience site. The upshot of the comments is that X commonly appears as a single-letter abbreviation for whole words that begin with the letters *ex*.

One of the earliest such uses may be in connection with the short form *PX*. The *X* in this initialism commonly stands for *exchange*, although the *P* in *PX* may stand for *private* in some cases or for *post* (or *postal*) in others. For example, from [*Western Electric Electrical Supply Year Book 1918*](https://books.google.com/books?id=U_hKAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22private+exchange+(PX)%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOm4Ojk-PwAhU9IjQIHa2pAhwQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22private%20exchange%20(PX)%22&f=false) (1918):

> Private Exchange (**P.X.**) and Private Branch Exchange (**P.B.X.**) switchboards , such as our sectional unit type, range in capacities from 20 to 80 lines and over. **P.X.** and **P.B.X.** boards are also made up in either desk or cabinet style, ranging in capacity from 60 to 600 lines.

From Federal Security Agency, Civilian Conservation Corps, "[Camp Life Arithmetic Workbook 5](https://books.google.com/books?id=s1FGAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22post+exchange%22+%22P+X%22+%22Through+the+P+X+the+company%22%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiD8ZSymePwAhUDP30KHdWqAqMQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22post%20exchange%22%20%22P%20X%22%20%22Through%20the%20P%20X%20the%20company%22%22&f=false)" (April 1941):

> The **Post Exchange** performs a service for the CCC which merchants perform for civil communities. Through the **P. X.** the company serves its members in the capacity of a merchant.

From "[Applause for Major Hastey](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$c241536&view=1up&seq=187&q1=%22post%20exchange%22%20PX)," in *Air Corps News Letter* (April 15, 1936):

> Probably all of us walk in and out of the **Post Exchange** more frequently than in any other building on the post. Our **PX** is still undergoing a length and breadth overhauling that is resulting in a store as modern as any **PX** on any post.

An earlier instance, in [*The Leatherneck*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=wu.89066031634&view=1up&seq=410&q1=PX) (July 1932) identifies the checkers champion at a post in Nevada as "Pfc. L. Leslie, PX book-keeper," indicating that *PX* was already in use in U.S. military jargon at that date.

Another early use of *X* to stand for a whole word beginning with the letters *ex* is in connection with clothing sizes, where the *X* stands for *extra*, as in *XS* (for "extra small") and *XL* (for "extra large") *XL* for "extra large." For example, from an [advertisement for Mead's Scarsdale](https://news.hrvh.org/veridian/cgi-bin/senylrc?a=d&d=scarsdaleinquire19440818.2.92.3&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22sizes+S%2c+M%22+XL------) in the *Scarsdale [New York] Inquirer* (August 18, 1944):

> SIZES S, M, L, AND **XL** IN UNDERSHIRTS 55¢ and 1.00

Somewhat older than that instance are instances from Australia of the short forms *XSSW* (for "extra slim small woman") and *XOS* (for "extra out sized"). For example, from an [advertisement for John's Silk Store](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/136584889?searchTerm=XSSW+XOS) in the *Newcastle [New South Wales] Morning Herald and Miners' Advocate* (June 16, 1932):

> **Face Cloth Coats.** Of superior quality, in ultra-smart styles, featuring inset backs of reversed material. Smart collars of large Coney fur. Colours include Brown, Navy, and Black. Sizes include **X.S.S.W.** to **X.O.S.**

As Roger Attrill details in his answer to the User Experience Stack Exchange question noted at the beginning of this answer, *X* has also seen service as a single-letter abbreviation for *executive* (in the initialism *AX*, short for "analyst executive"), *experience* (for example, in the initialism *VX*, short for "virtual experience), and *extremity* (in the initialism *LX*, short for "lower extremity"). *X* also shows up as a whole-word abbreviation in *X-Games* (where it stands for *extreme*), *XFG* (short for "exfoliation glaucoma"), *XGA* (short for "extended graphics array"), and *XML* (short for "extensible markup language").

Why did this seemingly odd tendency to use *X* rather than *E* as the signifying letter for certain *ex* words in initialisms arise in the first place? The answer may simply be that the relative rarity of words that begin with *x* recommended *X* as an alternative to *E* in order to reduce the likelihood of ambiguity. Compare [Wikipedia's list of acronyms that begin with *X*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_X) to [Wikipedia's list of acronyms that begin with E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_E), and you can see the appeal of using a relatively infrequent starting letter.

---

***Conclusions***

The use of *X* in the initialism *UX* to stand for *experience* does not follow an ironclad rule for dealing with words that begin with *ex*. For example, the acronym *ELF* is sometimes used as a short form for "extremely low frequency" and for "extraterrestrial life form"—although there is no competing widespread initialism *XLF* that might muddy the waters if that spelling were used for one of the terms instead.

Nevertheless, a considerable number of words beginning with *ex* are represented by the single letter *X* in various initialisms and other abbreviations. This practice has been around for more than a century, as the 1918 example containing *PX* and *PBX* (as short forms for "private exchange" and "private branch exchange, respectively) noted above confirms.

With regard to shortenings of the word *experience* to *X*, User Experience site participant Roger Attrill notes—in addition to *UX* for "user experience"—the kindred forms *CX* ("customer experience") and *VX* ("virtual experience").

There may be no formal rule at work here, but there is certainly a widespread (albeit sporadic) practice across multiple words beginning with *ex* to reduce them in initialisms to the single letter *X*.